# get personal Amazon purchase history and simiar titles

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm writing my own service to track my growing library and notify me of when books become available. I'm in the middle of 5 series waiting for the next book to come out. I also pick some up locally and would like to grab similar titles from amazon. How can I get my purchase history and similar titles? Is there an API for these? I haven't found anything from  searches.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Amazon exposes an API for order history.

The closest thing seems to be the product advertising API: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/Welcome.html

That would allow you to search for items, for example using ItemSearch:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemSearch.html

Alternatively, you probably could write a script scrape the data by navigating through the order history page, or to help you capture each page of results as you manually navigate your order history. You're on your own for this option, though.